# SQL fill in redundant values to table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to take the following table...

---

| City | Company | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New York | A | 400 |
| New York | B | 300 |
| Singapore | B | 400 |
| Washington D.C. | C | 400 |
| London | D | 400 |

and produce the below version.

---

| City | Company | Present | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| New York | A | 1 | 400 |
| New York | B | 1 | 300 |
| New York | C | 0 | 0 |
| New York | D | 0 | 0 |
| Singapore | A | 0 | 0 |
| Singapore | B | 1 | 400 |
| Singapore | C | 0 | 0 |
| Singapore | D | 0 | 0 |
| ... |  |  | ... |
| London | D | 1 | 400 |

So, basically filling extra company values to encompass the entire dataset, adding a 1 in the "Present" field if they are present, otherwise zero...

I hope my question makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull this off by first making a result set that has every combination of `company` and `city`. A `cross join` will do the trick here:

```
SELECT companies.company, cities.city 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Company FROM yourtable) companies,
  (SELECT DISTINCT City FROM yourtable) cities
```

We can now LEFT JOIN from that result set into your table to get to the final result set:

```
WITH all_values AS
(
  SELECT companies.company, cities.city 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Company FROM yourtable) companies,
      (SELECT DISTINCT City FROM yourtable) cities
)
SELECT all_values.company, 
    all_values.city,
    CASE WHEN yourtable.company IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Present,
    yourtable.Revenue
FROM 
    all_values
    LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable 
        ON all_values.company = yourtable.company
        AND all_values.city = yourtable.city;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select city.city
     , company.company
     , coalesce(t.Revenue, 0) 
     , case when t.revenue is not null then 1 else 0 end as Present
from (select distinct company from tablename) company
cross join (select distinct City from tablename) city
left join tablename t
   on t.city = city.city
   and t.company = company.company
```